# Call php artisan custom:command with an argument at the end without specifying the ones before

Tags: php, laravel, arguments, command, laravel-artisan

Is there any way that if I have a command of this kind:

```
protected $signature = 'custom:command {arg1} {arg2} {arg3?} {arg4?} {arg5?}';
```

To call it without specifying arg4, but with arg5? Something like:

```
php artisan custom:command arg1_val arg2_val arg3_val arg5_val
```

Of course, if I do it like above arg5_val will be interpreted like arg4_val and arg5 will be ignored.

I hope my question is clear and it was not answered already. Did not even have a clue how to search for it :))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [optional arguments](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#arguments)

```php
// Optional argument...
custom:command {arg5?}
```

.. but they need to be at the end. Otherwise the command does not know if an argument is left out.

Another way is to use [options](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#options-with-values). Then you can specify these with `option_name=option_value`

Comment: I get the use of optional arguments. This was just for one time I needed to run a command that had a lot of arguments (all of them optional) that I didn't need, but the one I needed was all the way to the back. I was hoping there was a way to skip putting something like ' ' where an optional argument was just because I didn't need it but I had to skip over it. The use of options seem to be what I was looking for, but I don't think it's worth to change the structure just because sometimes I need to run the command in a certain way. Apparently what I was looking for doesn't exist. Thanks.